# Can I call my close friends "Old Sport" nowadays?

Tags: slang

I wonder, can I call my close friends "Old Sport" nowadays? What about my close female friends?

Comment: You can say it, but you run the risk of sounding like you are using it with irony or like a hipster doofus.  (Perhaps those are synonymous.)

Comment: You could, but your style would probably be considered a bit awkward. These days, very few people say (no, correction: _no one_ says) things like, “I say, old chap, I do rather fancy the way you treated that poor girl wasn’t quite pukka sahib”, and that’s the kind of talk where ‘old sport’ belongs.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, "old chap", what about it? Can I use it as well?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: *no one*? You, sir, are nothing but a cad!

Answer (score 1):

Someone's been watching The Great Gatsby! :-) I'd say "Old Sport" is pretty outdated..Try saying "bro", "buddy" or, in British English, "mate".

Girls call there closest friends "sis" or "girl friend".

What do guys call their best "girl friend" (platonic)? To be honest, I don't know--probably it doesn't happen in real life. :-D

Comment: Gal pal is a good usage for that.

Comment: Louel, do you remember the thread titled *“How do we call (something) in English?”*?

Comment: In my experience, girls call each other by their names, or refer to them as friends.

Comment: @Tristanr I sure do. And?

Comment: It was the basis for why the last line of your answer, needed to be edited. You did it, which is an improvement.

Comment: You missed the one that comes most naturally to me (in AmE certainly, but also to a certain extent in BrE): _man_.

Comment: Then "dude" comes to mind as well. The only problem I have with "dude" and "man" is that these don't really communicate the closeness and warmth that "buddy", "bro", and "mate" suggest.

Comment: I’d say rather the opposite! ‘Man’ indicates intimacy, while ‘buddy’ can be downright distant. But I suspect this is not only regionally, but also idiolectically, conditioned. I _very_ rarely use ‘buddy’ except as a regular noun (and ‘bro’ even less—don’t think I’ve ever used the word, really), whereas I would quite naturally use ‘man’ as an epithet to friends.